# How to repaint the JComponent the MouseComponent is attached to?

Tags: java, swing, repaint

I made an 8x8 grid and I want the squares to repaint when clicked.

Each square in the grid is technically a ChessSquare (class I made that extends JComponent). There is a MouseListener that toggles an attribute of the ChessSquare and the paintComponent(Graphics g) of the ChessSquare is overridden to paint the component differently based on that attribute. The MouseListener is attached in the ChessSquare constructor.

What I am confused on is how to repaint the square at the end of the toggle method. What I tried was:

```
public void toggleIsTaken(){
if(isTaken){
        isTaken = false;
    } else {
        isTaken = true;
    }
    repaint();
}
```

This doesn't do anything on the click and I'm assuming that is because repaint isn't attached to anything specifically. I am unsure what exactly I could repaint for the square to be repainted. Any ideas?

Comment: `repaint` should make a request to the `RepaintManager` to schedule a repaint event on the Event Queue for the specified component, so yes, it should work. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I will work on creating the runnable example now, but when you say it repaints the specified component, how does it know what component is specified if I don't state that before I call repaint()? Are you saying that it should repaint whatever the listener is attached to?

Comment: It will `repaint` the component that made the request (itself)

Comment: Thanks. That was actually exactly what I needed. It helped me figured out that I was just drawing a line that went no where. I was treating drawLine like drawRect and specifying x,y,width,height with all 12 which went no where.